# I can't upgrade GLIBC 2.27 to GLIBC 2.2.8

Tags: 18.04

I wanna  upgrade to GLIBC 2.28

`ldd --version`

ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1.2) 2.27

I tried to do `sudo apt-get install libc6`

but it is still the same version not updating

Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

any advise?

Thanks

Comment: they are saying I have to upgrade my Ubuntu , which I don't want to do it now :(

Comment: Look at the packages that have *depends* rules on libc6, you'll find a lot of them.. many of which will also have their own *depends* rules meaning you'll need to upgrade a lot of your system, and it won't be your 18.04 anymore.